# do not create markers. Maps Google Android Studio. Java

Tags: java, google-maps-android-api-2

```
 double pointY[]=
  {59.927927619849,59.924231512202425,59.92453243804006,59.926455711411094};
  double pointX[]=
  {30.312396772205826,31.312396772205,29.31239677220582,30.312396772205826};

public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
  mMap = googleMap;

    List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < pointX.length; i++){
        points.add(new LatLng(pointX[i],pointY[i]));
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<points.size(); i++){

        mMap.addMarker(new 
        MarkerOptions().position(points.get(i)).title("r"));
      }

 }
```

The first cycle is working fine.
With the second cycle of problem markers are not created on the map. Are not created it through the loop if register separately generates.

Comment: Please tag which programming language you are using! Also, this may be the problem: `List<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();` the type on the left != the type on the right.

Comment: Android Studio programming language Java

Comment: There's nothing at all wrong with List<x> = ArrayList<x>. What do you mean by 'cycle'? The code you show just adds some points.

Comment: not created markers 
for (int i = 0; i<points.size(); i++){

        mMap.addMarker(new 
        MarkerOptions().position(points.get(i)).title("r"));
      }